# What is the name and origin of this golf format?

Tags: golf

- All players of a foursome tee-off.
- All four players hit their second shot from the location of the best drive.
- The group continues playing from the location of whoever has the best shot.
- However, at least 1 shot from each of the four players must be used each hole.  (But I suppose it's just understood that only 3 players would be used on a par 3 hole.)

I thought that was just "match play", but definitions vary.  I'm wondering if there is a specific name for that exact type of match play, and is there a known origin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like a scramble<sub>[(1)](http://golf.about.com/cs/golfterms/g/bldef_scramble.htm)[(2)](http://golftips.golfsmith.com/4-man-scramble-golf-1855.html)</sub>.

A scramble fulfills the first three requirements you list above:

> - All players of a foursome tee-off.
> - All four players hit their second shot from the location of the best drive.
> - The group continues playing from the location of whoever has the best shot.

The fourth requirement, "at least 1 shot from each of the four players must be used each hole," may be a variation of a scramble. I haven't found it in a specific scramble format, but the second source I reference states:

> Another variation is to not allow any player's shot to be used twice
>   in a row. This eliminates a team's ability to rely solely on one
>   standout player.

---

As far as a known origin, I have not been able to locate anything so far, but I will look into this.

Comment: "SCRAMBLE”!!  That is the word I was looking for.  That will do, but if there is anything that nails down that fourth requirement, it would be appreciated too.  Thanks for the help!